# Layout XML folder is missing in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout

Problem:

[image]

layout XML folder is missing?
How to add it?

Comment: Create xml file from res(right click) > new > add android resource file > enter file name, select resource type(Layout).

Comment: This is the `correct way` to add a layout folder: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51487755/4833705

Answer (score 11):

If the folder isn't there or wasn't added automatically when you created the project, you need to add it to your project in the following way:

- Right-click on the `res` folder
- Select New -> Android Resource Directory from the menu that opens
- Select Resource type to be `layout` from the popup that opens
- Click `ok`

Now you have added your `layout` folder, so you can now start adding `XML` files to this folder by the following steps:

- Right-click on the `layout` folder
- Select New -> Layout Resource File from the menu that opens
- Enter your new file name
- Click ok

Now you have a new XML file that you can use in any activity or fragment.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there was no xml file at all, thanks to the answer above I created my activity_main.xml file by myself, but then, I created some new fragments and there was no xml files for those also.

I was just like, "think simple". Then I invalidated caches and restarted my Android Studio, all xml files were there. Funny but that's how it works in my scenario. I hope it helps someone.

Answer (score -2):

After open the layout resource file and which new file name, can be typed

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).