# How to place admob ads to application without having activity_main.xml file

Tags: android, admob

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Iogr.png)I'm beginner to android studio . I downloaded code from this link :- https://github.com/jahirfiquitiva/Frames . In this code there is no activity_main.xml file . I want to place admob ads to this application . Can anyone help me to place admob ads to this "https://github.com/jahirfiquitiva/Frames" frames application .

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

Please don't get confuse with library and actual applications.

`https://github.com/jahirfiquitiva/Frames` is a library that you can [include into your project/app](https://github.com/jahirfiquitiva/Frames#including-in-your-project) using gradle -

```
dependencies {
    implementation('dev.jahir:Frames:3.3.0'@aar) {
        transitive = true
    }
}
```

After importing you can create your application and then you can put `admod` in your app's main layout file.

**Edit (Missing Layout Folder)**

If the folder isn't there or wasn't added automatically when you created the project, you need to add it to your project in the following way:

1. Right-click on the `res` folder
2. Select New -> Android Resource Directory from the menu that opens
3. Select Resource type to be layout from the popup that opens
4. Click OK

After creating the `res` folder you can add `layout` folder as well

1. Right-click on the layout folder
2. Select New -> Layout Resource File from the menu that opens
3. Enter your new file name
4. Click OK

Now you have XML file you can use into you activity/fragment.
Please check [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/add-resources) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48168658/layout-xml-folder-is-missing-in-android-studio) for more info.

Happy Coding !

Comment: I completed the process as you said before only . I can't find layout folder in application. Please help me to place ads.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Iogr.png please check this image for your clarification.